# How to specify multiplte schema in snowflake,pyspark connections

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have connections details as below and I need to read 2 tables from different schema (Employees and HR),

```
sfparams = {
  "sfURL" : "123.com",
  "sfUser" : "a",
  "sfPassword" : "b",
  "sfDatabase" : "Test",
  "sfSchema" : "Employee",
  "sfWarehouse" : "PD1"
}
```

How do I read data from HR schema?

Answer (score 1):

To read data from different schema two part names should be provided, i.e., `schema_name.table_name`:

```
df = spark.read.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME) \
  .options(**sfparams) \
  .option("query",  "select * from HR.table1") \
  .load()
```

Comment: hank you will give it a try